# How to execute sql lines in postgresql using python？

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, windows-8, psycopg2

I use postgresql 8.4 to route a river network, the following is my code typed in pgAdmin and the result is fine,

```
select * from driving_distance
('select gid as id,
 start_id::int4 as source, end_id::int4 as target,
 shape_leng::double precision as cost from network',
 10, 1000000, false, false);
```

[image]

I have installed psycopg2 and it successfully connect python and postgresql,

```
#set up python and postgresql connection
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'routing_template' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = '****'")
except:
    print 'I am unable to connect the database'
```

Now I need to directly execute my sql code on the top in pyscripter, how should I change these codes to python code？

I am working with postgresql 8.4, python 2.7.6 under Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: I have not used psycopg2, but have you considered using pyodbc instead? https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov thank you, In the very beginning I thought I need to use postgresql to handle shapefile data, so I choose psycopg2. Now I am reading Getting Started of pyodbc, but I really don't know which one has merit connecting to postgresql.

Comment: No, seriously, do *not* use PyODBC if psycopg2 is an option. psycopg2 is a _lot_ better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, never swallow an exception, or catch all exceptions. Your connection code should be more like:

```
import sys
import psycopg2

conn = None
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'routing_template' user = 'postgres' host = 'localhost' password = '****'")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, ex:
    print 'I am unable to connect the database: " + ex
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now, you have a connection. Running SQL is trivial ... as the psycopg2 tutorial would show you.

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT ...")
for row in curs:
   print row
```

You can be much more sophisticated about how you output row data, etc. [The manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) has [lots of useful examples](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have read the tutorial before, but I am too new to solve the sql problem, anyway, I will spend much more time to learn sql, thanks a lot!